# Implementing a AsyncTask with Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm migrating an app to Realm and I have an AsyncTask like this (simplified for brevity) that I used to search through a list of objects and filter it based on a search query:

```
private class SearchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void> {

Realm realm;

@Override
protected List<SearchResults> doInBackground(String... params) {

    String searchString = params[0];
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    ArrayList<SearchResults> myFoos = FooHelper.getAllFoo(realm);
    ArrayList<Foo> matches = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Foo aFoo : myFoos){
      if(!aFoo.getProperty().isEmpty()){
        matches.add(aFoo);
      }
    }

    realm.close();
    return matches;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<SearchResults> results) {
    super.onPostExecute(results);

    synchronized (SearchActivity.this){
      //use search results
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that when the results are returned they can't be accessed since they were created on another thread. The only solution I can think of is to return an array of primary keys from the async task then re-query for those again.

There has to be a better way of basically doing SEARCH on a realm. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Until fairly recently realm did not support asynchronous queries at all.

You'll be happy to know this has changed but you don't do it via async task. Heres the documentation on how to do it:

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-queries

Comment: Interesting...One problem that I have with using the queries is that I have an array of contacts with a firstName and lastName and i want to search on the full name (which isn't a property of the RealmObject).

Previously in my AsyncTask i just joined the first and last into another string like "First Last" so that i could match on a query like "First L" and it would still match.

 Is the "Realm" way to do this just to create a new variable on the object called fullName? Seems like overkill a bit.